# PHP : array in Format part to sprintf or vprintf

Tags: php, arrays, printf

Student of PHP Even Now ! 
Searched for this but haven't got any answer So posting the Q

i know about

```
sprintf ( string format [, mixed args])
```

> sprintf  Description :Returns a string produced according to the formatting string
>   format.

and

```
vsprintf ( string format, array args)
```

Though these are pretty good enough i just ran through a problem

is there any simple way to (i mean a pretty good than iteration and `sprintf` each) 
**"Returns an array produced according to the formatting array format. "** ( Desc:copied from sprintf )

i have a general $product  array

```
$product = array( 
           "p_id" => '%s', 
           "u_price" => '%s', 
           "qty" => '%d'
          );

   $newProductArray1= sprintf_special($product,"Tomato","30","12");
   $newProductArray2= sprintf_special($product,"Carrot","20","10");
```

So that

```
 $newProductArray1= ( 
               "p_id" => 'Tomato', 
               "u_price" => '30', 
               "qty" => '12'
              )

$newProductArray2= ( 
               "p_id" => 'Carrot', 
               "u_price" => '20', 
               "qty" => '10'
              )
```

NB:  i don't want to make a product class though! :)

Comment: No, there's no such thing. `$product['p_id'] = 'Tomato'` and the like for the rest, or just define the array that way to begin with `$product = array('p_id'] => 'Tomato', etc....)`.

Comment: @Nifty Waiting for some crazy one to Answer this ,   winked through  goooogling ...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're after array_combine, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php.

So in your case:

```
$product_keys = array( 
           "p_id", 
           "u_price", 
           "qty"
          );

$newProductArray1= array_combine($product_keys, array("Tomato","30","12"));
$newProductArray2= array_combine($product_keys, array('Carrot', '20', '10'));
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your finding , i am looking for a better  bro of sprintf . the given scenario in my Q  is much simpler any way